# What are the odds of any role of a 24 sided die occurring 4 or more times in 10 rolls?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Note that I am not asking about the odds of a chosen roll happening 4 times in 10 rolls, (this has a probability of 0.000517 according to a binomial calculator), rather, the odds of ANY roll happening 4 or more times in 10 rolls.

Another way to ask it is: What are the odds that the mode of the list of 10 rolls of the die will be 4 or more? 
In general how is this calculated?
Thank you.

Comment: Can't you extend that to X = 4,5,...10 using the same binomial calculator where p = 1/24 and (1-p) = 23/24.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @satishramanathan That would work for four or more occurrences of a fixed value, not for four copies of *any* value.

Comment: @satish yes, you are missing something.  The event that "one does not occur 4 or more times" is not independent from the event "two does not occur 4 or more times."

Comment: @JMoravitz, My apologies, I misread.  This is early morning out here.  The OP was clear but my brain is sluggish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $i$ is an integer between $1$ and $24$, and let $A_i$ be the event that you roll an $i$ at least $4$ times in ten rolls. Notice that two of the $A_i$ could occur, but not three, since that would be twelve different rolls.

By the [inclusion/exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), you get that $$\mathbb{P}(\cup A_i) = \sum \mathbb{P}(A_i) - \sum_{i\ \neq j}\mathbb{P}(A_i \cap A_j).$$ You have already calculated $\mathbb{P}(A_i)$ for each $i$. Now you have to calculate $\mathbb{P}(A_i \cap A_j)$ for $i \neq j$, which is a little trickier (unless I'm missing an easier way).

To do this, you should add up

- the number of ways of rolling (*exactly*) four $i$s and exactly four $j$s,
- ...of rolling four $i$s and five $j$s,
- ...of rolling five $i$s and four $j$s (same as
  above),
- ...of rolling five $i$s and five $j$s,
- ...of rolling six $i$s and four $j$s, and
- ...of rolling six $j$s and four $i$s (same as
  above).

This is $$22^2 \binom{10}{8}\binom{8}{4} + 2 \cdot 22 \cdot \binom{10}{9}\binom{9}{5} + \binom{10}{5} + 2 \cdot\binom{10}{6}.$$

Call that number $n$ for brevity. Dividing $n$ by $24^{10}$ will give you $\mathbb{P}(A_i \cap A_j)$, given $i$ and $j$. Now add up all the different choices of $i$ and $j$ to give you (assuming you did your previous calculation right) $$\mathbb{P}(\cup A_i)= 24 \cdot (.000517) - \binom{24}{2}\frac{n}{24^{10}}$$

Comment: This will help a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Outline: We use Inclusion/Exclusion.

Find in one of the usual ways the probability of say $1$ coming up $4$ or more times.  Multiply by $24$, and call the result $a$.

However, this double-counts the ways in which $2$ faces come up $4$ or more times. (We cannot have more than $2$ faces coming up $4$ or more times.)
So we will have to subtract the probability of $2$ faces coming up $4$ or more times.

Which $2$ faces? They can be chosen in $\binom{24}{2}$ ways. So let us find  the probability that (say) faces $1$ and $2$ can come up $4$ or more times, multiply by $\binom{24}{2}$, and subtract the result from $a$.

The face $1$ can come up $4$, $5$, or $6$ times. The simplest case is $6$, for then we find the probability of $6$ $1$'s and $4$ $2$'s.

For face $1$ coming up $5$ times, we can have face $2$ coming up $4$ or $5$ times. The probabilities can be calculated. The same is true for face $1$ coming up $4$ times, but then there are three cases for face $2$.

Unpleasant, but one can push it through.